# Form1 disappears when focus is on Form1 and browser window loses focus

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5

I have a problem when my Form1 appear on body of browser window, simply he disappear when I put focus in my Form and  the  browser window lose focus. How solved it? Any suggestion will welcome.

See image below:

[image]

and here is my complete code:

Unit for enumeration of windows (EnumWindowUtil_.pas):

```
unit EnumWindowUtil_;

interface
uses
  Winapi.Windows,
  System.SysUtils,
  System.Classes;
type
  TWindowList = class(TStringList)
  private
    FAddClassname: Boolean;
  public
    procedure EnumChildWindows(handle: HWND);
    property AddClassname: Boolean read FAddClassname write FAddClassname;
  end;

  var
  wlistChilds: TWindowList;

implementation

  function GetWindowClassName(hwnd: HWND): string;
  begin
    SetLength(Result, 1024);
    GetClassName(hwnd, PChar(Result), Length(Result));
    Result := PChar(Result);
  end;

  procedure EnumWindowCallback(hwnd: HWND; lParam: TWindowList); stdcall;
  var
    buffer: array[0..255] of char;
    texto: string;
  begin
    if (not IsWindowVisible(hwnd)) then
      Exit;

    SendMessage(hwnd, $000D, 256, Integer(@buffer));
    texto := StrPas(buffer);
    texto := texto + ':' + GetWindowClassName(hwnd) + ' - ' + Format('%6.6x', [hwnd]) + '/' + IntToStr(hwnd);
    lParam.AddObject(texto, TObject(hwnd));
  end;

  procedure TWindowList.EnumChildWindows(handle: HWND);
  begin
    Clear;
    if Winapi.Windows.EnumChildWindows(handle, @EnumWindowCallback, Integer(Self)) then;
  end;
end.
```

Here is main unit:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.ExtCtrls, EnumWindowUtil_,
  Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Timer1: TTimer;
    procedure Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;
  linha: string;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

function GetNavigatorHandle(BASE: HWND): HWND;
var
  I: integer;
begin
  linha:= '';
  Result := 0;
  wlistChilds := TWindowList.Create;
  wlistChilds.AddClassname := True;
  wlistChilds.EnumChildWindows(BASE);

  for I := 0 to wlistChilds.Count - 1 do
  begin
    linha := wlistChilds.Strings[I];

    if
       (Pos('Chrome_Render',linha)>0)then
    begin
      Result := StrToInt(copy(linha, pos('/', linha) + 1, Length(linha)));
      Break;
    end;
  end;
  FreeAndNil(wlistChilds);
end;

procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
var
   janela, janelaContainer: HWND;
begin
   janela := GetForegroundWindow;

   janelaContainer := GetNavigatorHandle(Janela);
   if janelaContainer = 0 then
   begin
      Exit;
   end;
   Winapi.Windows.SetParent(form1.handle,janelaContainer);
end;

end.
```

Comment: I'd rather try setting ParentWindow. I refrain myself querying your design...

Comment: What is the code doing? What is that SetParent call for?

Comment: @David Heffernan, the code above put a child window (my Form1) in body of window browser using an enumeration of windows and the Winapi.Windows.SetParent method, when foreground window is the browser :), but simply my Form disappear when I put focus in my Form and the browser window lose focus :(. Any suggestion?

Comment: You cannot expect SetParent to be useful here. What is your goal?

Comment: My goal is that my Form1 stay into window browser (on body in this case), if I use another method and not SetParent, my Form will stay outside of window browser.

Comment: It isn't going to work. SetParent cross process is for compat with 16 bit windows. Define "into" please. Child window, or owned window.

Comment: @Coringa - Did you see my comment?

Comment: Then really my Form1 stay totaly visible only when window of browser is foreground. In this case, my problem not have a solution :(

Comment: @SertacAkyuz, Yes, I saw your comment, but not understood your suggestion. Could you give me a example?

Comment: form1.ParentWindow := janelaContainer, instead of the SetParent call.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz That's just not going to be any use when the other window is in a different process.

Comment: @Coringa What you need is for the browser window to be the **owner** of your window. And I mean owner in the Windows sense. You can make your window be owned by overriding CreateParams on the form and setting Params.WndParent to the window handle that you want to own your window. You may need to re-create the window.

Comment: @David - It will be of some use. It will at least take into account the child flag - which will help with the deactivation of the parent or activation of the form itself. It will also help with focus issues. Of course it will not make all problems go away in an unsupported scheme, no one-liner will.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan and Sertac Akyuz, this problem is only in Google Chrome. Others as: IE and Safari, works fine. So, this trouble is due to the browser not the application :D.

Comment: I don't think I can help any more because I've still no real idea what you are trying to do. If you can't make it clear what you are attempting then it's hard to help.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, the main goal is make my Form1 not stay like appear image above when he receives focus :). With others browsers as: IE and Safari, it works as must work.

Comment: Nope, I've still no idea what you mean. Never mind.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, tests my code above and checks my last comment here, that you will understand the problem better! :)

Comment: Nope. If you can't explain it then I can't help.

Comment: I verified your issue. The browser seems to be rendering over the form - can't blame it, it's not aware that there's a window there.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz, thank you for your analysis. I'm happy because you understood the problem :). In IE and Safari for example, this no happens and works correctly. This have some solution to works fine in Google Chrome?

Comment: I don't think so. Try making your form a sibling of the renderer frame, IOW parent it in the top level browser window. If it doesn't go against what you're doing of course..

Comment: What I find strange is that it's quite worse with the WS_CHILD style.

Comment: @Sertac I cannot understand why you are encouraging cross process parenting.

Comment: @Sertac Asker is pleased that you understand and still believes that cross process parenting is a good idea.

Comment: @David - I think understanding the problem and encouraging are different things. You may have a point about that I haven't really been discouraging though. I don't think I have been any help anyway..

Comment: My dears, I already that this trouble is because of particularities browsers, then let's this forget :)